# SSH to AWS Ec2: port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, aws

I am trying to ssh(from my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop) to a running EC2 instance

```
ssh -i /home/miki/pizda/jk/keys/kur/kjam/python-kjam.pem ubuntu@ec2-18-194-207-247.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-18-194-207-247.eu-central-1.compute.amazonkur.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

The same If I try IP

```
ssh -i /home/miki/pizda/jk/keys/kur/kjam/python-kjam.pem ubuntu@18.194.207.247
ssh: connect to host 18.194.207.247 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can ping IP

```
ping 18.194.207.247
PING 18.194.207.247 (18.194.207.247) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 18.194.207.247 ping statistics ---
544 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 556011ms
```

Why do I have 100% packet loss? How to set security groups?
[image]
 What else could cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a local firewall on the instance - `iptables` - that blocks your ssh traffic.

You can use [AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ssm-session-manager/) and [**ssm-session**](https://aws.nz/projects/ssm-session/) to access the instance and then run `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT` and see if you can SSH to it. If it works you can then setup your firewall properly.

Hope that helps :)